# Rails "superclass mismatch for class (TypeError)". A well documented error, but I need some tailored advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, heroku

Ok. I understand why I'm getting this error. According to another StackOverflow question, "That error shows up when you redeclare a class that’s already been declared". This question seems to point out the solutions, but not quite. I have some additional questions.

Here's what I have...

/models/item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
end

class Theme < Item
end

class Setting < Item
end
```

This Item model has existed for quite some time. I recently added the sing inheritance for Theme and Setting.

As well as...

/models/setting.rb

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
end
```

/models/theme.rb

```
class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
end
```

So it makes sense why I'm getting the error. I never got the error in my local workspace, only when I pushed everything to heroku, did my migrations, and then tried to run "heroku run rails c". As soon as I run that command, I get the error and immediately get booted out.

According to some answers, I should quit console and come back in. However, I can't get in to begin with. As soon as I launch "heroku run rails c", I get booted.

Additionally, if I completely wipe my DB, and remigrate everything, am I going to get the same error given the order of operations of these table creates, etc? I don't want to have to hack a solution to fix it everytime. If I run all my migrations, ideally everything would be working straight away.

What do I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to redefine the `Theme` and the `Setting` model. In your `app/models/item.rb` you define them as inherited from `Item` class and in the `app/models/theme.rb` and `app/models/setting.rb` you define them to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` directly.

You can see this error only in the heroku (probably production) environment because in dev env the eager loding option is turned off by default and therefore Rails does not load in all the classess when it boots.

Is your `Item` model using single table inheritance (STI)? Because that is the only case when you need to inherit the `Theme` and `Settings` model from your `Item` model.

If it is move your `Theme` and `Setting` class definitions to the `app/models/theme.rb` and `app/models/setting.rb` files accordingly and remove the definitions from there.

If not, then simply remove the `Theme` and `Setting` class definitions from the `app/models/item.rb` file and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Very thorough and concise explanation, clearest I've ever read on here, thank you very much for that. Yes, using STI. Easy fix, thanks again!